# How Do I Save a Portion of the DB So that I can Load it Back up Later

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So, I just did a lot of work setting up my development environment to recreate a situation. Its pretty complex.

Right now, I'm ready to debug it, but I'm fearful of doing so because after its done, I'll have to rebootstrap my DB and then redo all that complex information again.

Is there anyway to set up the DB so that I can have a point to reset it to after a debugging session?

Like say I have a value in my DB that is perhaps "hello world". I push a button on a website and it changes that value to "hey there".

The project is a lot more complex and has a lot more data than that. Is there anyway to save it at "hello world", and when the change is made to "hey there", I can revert it back to that "hello world" state and then retry the command again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just take a DB snapshot at the "hello world" state, and then restore it after your change? that sounds like the easiest way to do this while you debug.

To dump: `mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD your_db > your_db.sql`

To restore: `mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD your_db < your_db.sql`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Saving as aliases!